# Cypress code to check text in a button that has been created after uploading a file

Tags: cypress

When I upload a file, a view button is created which I am running a check on it.
Is there a way in Cypress to get this element by checking on the next increment of

```
'#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvScannedDocuments_ctl02_btnView'
```

would be

```
'#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvScannedDocuments_ctl**03**_btnView'
```

Basically so it is running the check on the newly created 'view' button and not the previous one. Thanks

Comment: cy.get('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvScannedDocuments_ctl02_btnView').should('have.text', 'View') This is where i am but check is always done on ctl02 and not current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When targeting an id you can use two forms of selector

- `cy.get('#my-id')`          - as you have shown above
- `cy.get('[id="my-id"]')`    - alternatively treat id as an attribute

If you switch to the second format, you can apply [starts-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

This means the get query will actually return every button that starts with that part of the `id`.

So, perhaps you then apply the `.last()` command to just filter the last one in the list? (Works if the buttons are added in order down the page or accross the page, since Cypress queries scan top-left to bottom-right).

```js
cy.get('[id^="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvScannedDocuments_ctl"]')
  .last()                                                          // last on page
  .should('have.text', 'View')
```

But if you want to be really sure, instead of using `.last()` add some code to apply a sort on the `id` and take the highest - something like:

```js
cy.get('[id^="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvScannedDocuments_ctl"]')
  .then($els => {
    const ids = $els.map(function() { return this.id; }).get()
    ids.sort()
    const highestId = ids.pop()
    return $els.filter(highestId)
  })
  .should('have.text', 'View')
```